# How to use maximize groupbox using GUI in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, groupbox

I would like to create a group box in my GUI form. I use windowsState maximized for my form. And I want to use the group box, and I need to make the group box also maximized but combine with margin and padding. So the size and position of the group box will not change even the resolution screen change.
I tried this, but it does not work.
Anyone can help me. Thank you.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"
$Form.MaximizeBox                = $false
$Form.startposition              = "centerscreen"
$Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'


$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.text                  = "Group Box"
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,13)
$Groupbox1.Padding               = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Padding -ArgumentList (0,5,5,0)
$Groupbox1.Margin                = 2,2,2,2

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Groupbox1))
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create a panel first of 100% width and height. Then put the groupbox inside the panel, this should work:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"
$Form.MaximizeBox                = $false
$Form.startposition              = "centerscreen"
$Form.WindowState                = 'Maximized'

$Panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$panel.Dock = "Fill"
$panel.ColumnCount = 1
$panel.RowCount = 1
$panel.CellBorderStyle = "single"
$panel.ColumnStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 100)))
$panel.RowStyles.Add((new-object System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle([System.Windows.Forms.SizeType]::Percent, 100)))

$Groupbox1                       = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Groupbox
$Groupbox1.text                  = "Group Box"
$Groupbox1.location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,13)
$Groupbox1.Padding               = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Padding -ArgumentList (0,5,5,0)
$Groupbox1.Dock                  = "fill"

$form.controls.add($Panel)
$panel.controls.AddRange(@($Groupbox1))
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Yes, Perfectly! Thank you so much Bro!

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help.

Comment: Hi, I have plan to add more groupbox inside groupbox1. But I have a problem when I want to set the location of the second groupbox. Could you please give me any idea? Thank you